# Cache layers automatically in TileCache?

Tags: mapserver, tilecache

I'm using TileCache with MapServer as background application server. In GeoWebCache (GeoServer) caching can be done manually or software itself generates if any tiles are not found. In TileCache caching can be done by using `tilecache_seed.py layername minzoomlevel maxzoomlevel` in command prompt.

My question is how to do caching/seeding automatically in tilecache software as similar to Geowebcache?

Comment: Both GeoWebCache and TileCache will automatically ask the configured source to render needed tiles that are not yet in the cache. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: As I know, After configuration of server, in geo-webcache you no need to seed tiles manually, whenever a service calls first time   from openlayers or any map library front end it will generate tiles (i.e png files) automatically. But in case of tilecache you have to seed layer initially other wise it will give/show error or empty tile.